# Unrecognized argument 'ComputerName'. All arguments must begin with "-"

Tags: powershell, web-deployment, webdeploy

```
msdeploy.exe : Error: Unrecognized argument 'ComputerName='https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd''. All arguments must begin with "-".
At C:\Users\scheluka\Desktop\copy.ps1:11 char:1
+ & 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Unrecogn...begin with "-".:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error count: 1.
```

```cs
& 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' `
-source:iisApp=`'C:\Work\US17830_Latest\webapps\orchestration_snwatchlist\apps`' `
-dest:iisApp=`'Default Web Site/test/vmes`' ,ComputerName=`'https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd`',UserName=$username,Password=$password,IncludeAcls=`'False`',AuthType=`'Basic`' `
-verb:sync `
-verbose `
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension `
-disableLink:ContentExtension `
-disableLink:CertificateExtension `
-allowUntrusted `
-retryAttempts=2 `
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.bin
```

Comment: ``-dest:iisApp=`'Default Web Site/test/vmes`' ,ComputerName=`'https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd`',UserName=$username,Password=$password,IncludeAcls=`'False`',AuthType=`'Basic`'`` -> `"-dest:iisApp='Default Web Site/test/vmes' ,ComputerName='https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd',UserName=$username,Password=$password,IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic'"`

Comment: you can put all those string options in a string array and call that with `Your.exe $Options`. that will remove the need for all those backticks since you won't have the need to embed single quotes - use outer double quotes and inner singletons - or the reverse. something like this `"-source:iisApp='C:\Work\US17830_Latest\webapps\orchestration_snwatchlist\apps/'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Over use of the backtick.
The comma is a natural break in PowerShell as are other operation characters.

If you are after human readability and wanting to avoid those long lines (I understand - but there are cases where they are unavoidable), then you can try these options...

```
# 1 
& 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' "-source:iisApp='C:\Work\US17830_Latest\webapps\orchestration_snwatchlist\apps' -dest:iisApp='Default Web Site/test/vmes',
ComputerName='https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd',
UserName=$username,
Password=$password,
IncludeAcls='False',
AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -verbose -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -allowUntrusted -retryAttempts=2 -skip:objectName=filePath,
absolutePath=.bin"



# 2
$Arguments = "-source:iisApp='C:\Work\US17830_Latest\webapps\orchestration_snwatchlist\apps' 
-dest:iisApp='Default Web Site/test/vmes',
ComputerName='https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd',
UserName=$username,
Password=$password,
IncludeAcls='False',
AuthType='Basic' 
-verb:sync 
-verbose 
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension 
-disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-allowUntrusted 
-retryAttempts=2 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.bin" 

# If you view the variable content it will show as it looks, but it's really a single line
$Arguments
$Arguments.Count
$Arguments.Length


& 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' """$Arguments"""


# 3 - if the exe does not see the above as a single line. You can make it one on the fly
$Arguments = "-source:iisApp='C:\Work\US17830_Latest\webapps\orchestration_snwatchlist\apps' 
-dest:iisApp='Default Web Site/test/vmes',
ComputerName='https://QMX-STG-WEB2:8172/msdeploy.axd',
UserName=$username,
Password=$password,
IncludeAcls='False',
AuthType='Basic' 
-verb:sync 
-verbose 
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension 
-disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-allowUntrusted 
-retryAttempts=2 
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.bin" -replace "`n|`r"

# this makes sure it see a line
"""$Arguments""" | clip # Just paste in to notepad to see the line. Well as long as notepad is not set to word wrap

& 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' """$Arguments"""
```